# Replying to Chatter Email Notifications

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

How to get dynamically Replying to Chatter Email address for a post feed item.

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/collab_email_reply.htm

> Before replying, check the email address that displays in the To field
>   of your email. Valid addresses contain tokens, or long character
>   strings, both before and after the @ symbol, such as
>   w8t27apy1@j321imd9gbs.d8rx.d.chatter.na1.salesforce.com. Some email
>   applications may automatically use the From address from the original
>   email, reply@chatter.salesforce.com, which is not a valid address for
>   receiving replies. If you see this shortened address in the To field
>   of your reply email, replace it with the valid reply-to address in the
>   email header information. For example, in an application such as IBM®
>   Lotus Notes®:

I want to fetch dynamic address token or long character strings.

Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Do you want to extract the reply to address in an email client or in code (such as Apex/Java/C#)?

Comment: I want to extract in Apex.